# how to combine annotation and style in Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

this might be a dumb question, but I'm trying to get a text with style AND a tag, which currently is done like so:

```kotlin
buildAnnotatedString {
            append(stringResource(id = R.string.pleaseClick))

          
            withAnnotation("Here", "Here") {
                withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = lightRed)) {
                    append(context.getString(R.string.here))
                }
            }
            append(stringResource(id = R.string.ifYouAreNotRedirectedWithin))
        }
```

however (as you may noticed) this has 2 faults:

1. it looks ugly
2. it does not allow me to use compose "stringResource" within the `withStyle` block

how can I handle this in a better way? (fyi: I need that to make a part of a string clickable AND have a different look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [push/pop](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/AnnotatedString.Builder#pushStringAnnotation(kotlin.String,kotlin.String)) syntax to solve your problem:

```kotlin
append(stringResource(R.string.pleaseClick))
pushStringAnnotation("here", "https://example.com")
withStyle(SpanStyle(Color.Red)) {
    append(stringResource(R.string.here))
}
pop()
append(stringResource(R.string.ifYouAreNotRedirected))
```